# iterating over column values and check for inside values

Tags: python, pandas

sorry, I am new to python.
suppose, I have a data frame with column values repeating at some intervals

| dest_num | dest_voltage | changes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 322 | 45.1 | stops responding |
| 322 | 45.5 | battery |
| 322 | 46.7 | low voltage |
| 322 | 43.2 | none |
| 322 | 42.1 | none |
| 322 | 41.1 | stops responding |
| 322 | 45.1 | battery |
| 322 | 43.4 | low voltage |
| 322 | 43.2 | none |
| 322 | 42.1 | critical voltage |
| 322 | 40.1 | dest_outage |

here , as we can see stops responding comes in twice and has low voltage both the times but critical voltage and dest_outage only once.
is there a way to iterate through all the "stops responding" and check if all the three column values "low voltage","critical voltage" and "dest_outage" occur and create another data frame only from the filtered condition?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a numeric id for each group, where the group starts on `stops responding`.  You can do this by checking if `changes` equals `stops responding` and take the cumulative sum of the results.

Using this grouping you can check if all the values in your required list are in the `changes` column for that group and filter the results if they are.

You can of course drop the group column if it's no longer needed, but it seems like that might also be helpful after the fact.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'dest_num': [322, 322, 322, 322, 322, 322, 322, 322, 322, 322, 322],
 'dest_voltage': [45.1,45.5,46.7,43.2,42.1,41.1,45.1,43.4,43.2,42.1,40.1],
 'changes': ['stops responding','battery','low voltage','none','none',
  'stops responding','battery','low voltage','none','critical voltage',
  'dest_outage']})

values = ['low voltage','critical voltage','dest_outage']
df['group'] = df['changes'].eq('stops responding').cumsum()
df.groupby('group').filter(lambda x: all([v in x['changes'].values for v in values]))
```

Output

```
   dest_num dest_voltage    changes            group
5   322     41.1            stops responding    2
6   322     45.1            battery             2
7   322     43.4            low voltage         2
8   322     43.2            none                2
9   322     42.1            critical voltage    2
10  322     40.1            dest_outage         2
```